# Kiel oni nomas @?

Tags: technology

En diversaj lingvoj la signo @ havas diversajn nomojn. En la sveda ni diras *snabel-a* (rostro-a), en la angla estas *at-sign* (ĉe-signo) kaj mi aŭdis ke en la ĉina oni nomas ĝin "flora a". Kiel oni diras en Esperanto?

Answer (score 11):

Krom “**ĉe**” kaj la pli oficiala (sed persone neniam aŭdita) ***po-signo***, ReVo ankaŭ mencias la neformalan vorton “**heliko**”.

*Saŭco: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/cgi-bin/sercxu.pl?sercxata=po%2Dsigno&x=on&kadroj=1*

Comment: I suppose *saŭco* must be a typo. But how is it correctly?

Comment: Estas stulta traduko de 'sauce' kiu estas stulte uzata anstataŭ 'source' en kelkaj sociaj retejoj kiel Imgur aŭ Reddit.

Comment: Oh, an in-joke then. Dankon!

Answer (score 7):

La kutima nomo estas "po-signo". En retadresoj oni ofte prononcas ĝin “ĉe”.

Answer (score 4):

Se oni aŭskultus tiun sondosieron, oni aŭdus, ke ŝi uzas la vorton **ĉe** por la retpoŝtadreso de Ana:
http://lernu.net/en/biblioteko/119

Laŭ REVO, la nomo estas **po-signo**: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/cgi-bin/sercxu.pl?sercxata=po%2Dsigno&x=on&kadroj=1

Answer (score 0):

En retpoŝta adreso, oni kutime diras **"ĉe"**.

Laŭ la libro [Kauderwelsch Band 56: Esperanto - Wort für Wort](https://web.archive.org/web/20210918164417/https://www.reise-know-how.de/de/produkte/kauderwelsch-buch/esperanto-wort-fuer-wort-255) kaj [laŭ vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliko_(apartigilo)) la nomo de la signo "@" estas **"heliko"** (kiel la besto:)

[image: foto de helika besto]
Foto CC BY 2.0 [macrophile](https://flickr.com/photos/macrophile)

[Laŭ ReVo, "heliko" estas "[n]eformala nomo de la signo @"](http://kono.be/cgi-bin/vivo/ViVo.cgi?pagxo=helik.#helik.0o.ascii) kaj [alia (do la formala?) nomo estas **"po-signo"**](http://kono.be/cgi-bin/vivo/ViVo.cgi?pagxo=po.#po.0_signo).

[Respondo de la Lingva Konsultejo](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/akademio/index.php?title=Respondoj_de_la_Konsultejo#La_nomo_de_la_signo_.40) de la Akademio de Esperanto al simila demando mencias la sekvajn eblojn:

- "ĉe"
- "ĉe-signo"
- "heliko"

  - «aŭ, pli precize, "helika a"»
- "po"
- "po-signo"